# VBA Import First Worksheet from Closed workbook to Active Workbook

Tags: vba

I'm having trouble modifying this code to copy the first worksheet of a closed workbook and import it to the active workbook. It wants to copy all worksheets and it adds "after:=WB.Sheets(WB.Sheets.Count)" to a random cell in the sheet. 
Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
Dim WB As Workbook
Dim SourceWB As Workbook
Dim WS As Worksheet
Dim ASheet As Worksheet

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False

Set WB = ActiveWorkbook
Set ASheet = ActiveSheet
Set SourceWB = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\ME\Desktop\Book1.xlsx") 

For Each WS In SourceWB.Worksheets
    WS.Copy after:=WB.Sheets(WB.Sheets.Count)
Next WS

    SourceWB.Close savechanges:=False
    Set WS = Nothing
    Set SourceWB = Nothing

WB.Activate
ASheet.Select
    Set ASheet = Nothing
    Set WB = Nothing

Application.EnableEvents = True
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub copyFirstWS()
    Dim wb As Workbook

    Set wb = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\ME\Desktop\Book1.xlsx")

    With ThisWorkbook
        wb.Worksheets(1).Copy After:=.Worksheets(.Worksheets.Count)
    End With

    wb.Close savechanges:=False
End Sub
```

Comment: Works perfect. I really appreciate your help!